# working on debugging for a class can someone tell me why this discount calculator is not working?

Tags: python, function, debugging, math, calculator

```
def calcDiscountPrice(price, percentage):

    discount = price * percentage

    discountPrice = price - discount

    return discount
```

I am expecting the code to take the price and have it print the discounted prices total.

Comment: Why do you calculate `discountPrice` but don't return it?

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You don't have a print call in your code. Problem is not reproducable this way.